# How to know when phone was last rebooted?

Tags: ios, reboot, touch-id

Occasionally I get the message about TouchID needing my password after reboot on an iPhone 5s running iOS 8. Problem is, I haven't been rebooting my phone, so the message is confusing to me.

So I'm concerned my phone is rebooting itself in my pocket without me knowing it. I want to know for sure if my phone is rebooting by itself, or if the TouchID message is just erroneous.

How can I find out if my phone is rebooting by inspecting the logs for power off / power on events?

Comment: sometimes just resetting off/on the cellular would fix that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There appears to be an app called "System Status Lite" that is capable of displaying the system uptime (which should be the time since the last reboot). I haven't used it myself, so I can't speak to its accuracy, but here's a [store link.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/system-status-lite-battery/id407752428?mt=8)

Comment: Works. Good find. Seems accurate.