# How to see last restart/shutdown time of iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I see the last time that my iPhone shut down without installing any apps?

[How to know when phone was last rebooted?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/172009/how-to-know-when-phone-was-last-rebooted) is 8 years old and only says "install System Status Lite" (third party app), which is exactly what I am asking this question to get around

Comment: Not sure there's a way without third-party apps. Maybe there's some info in Settings > Battery? You could charge your iPhone and see in Settings > Battery the time at which the battery starts increasing quicker - very bad solution but the only one I see.

Comment: @thinkr a straight reboot most likely doesn‘t show up in Settings->Battery. If you find a way, please post the answer to original question.

Comment: @nohillside Yep possibly. I've found an answer (as explained in the comment - which possibly doesn't cover the reboot) but as I've said, it's very bad.